# Keep running IIS Express and my web page after closing visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I would like to know if there is a way to keep IIS express and my web page running after closing Visual Studio. I am not just closing debug session but I want to close Visual studio itself. 
Is it possible?
If nor, can I achieve that using command prompt?

Comment: Why not use normal IIS? It runs outside of VS.

Comment: Thanks for reply
How can I use normal IIS?
Can you provide me steps or point to some document which can help me to understand?

Answer (score 0):

It could be your project settings. Please check if you have enabled edit and continue in debug mode:

In Visual Studio, right click your web project in the Solutions Explorer > click Properties > select the 'Web' tab on the left pane > uncheck the 'Enable Edit and Continue' checkbox on the right pane.

Then run your web project and the IIS Express should retain listing of your web site even after you stop debugging.

I must say it wouldn't retain the web site after closing Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure there is anyway to keep open IIS Express.but
you can host website on local IIS to access your website or webpage

Comment: Hi Hitesh
Can you please provide some exmaple on how to do that?

Comment: can i know that what you want exactly keep open IIS Express or you want that website should be running ?

Comment: Yes I want my web page running!

Comment: you need to host your website in local iis and for that you can take reference from here http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1247/how-to-host-aspnet-application-on-the-web-server-iis